# Choosing between .NET and Java to run on Mac and PC

Tags: java, .net, windows, macos

I need to write software that would be running on both Windows and Mac.

What is the better technology to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: This depends on the type of software you are trying to create.

Comment: You're much more likely to get *better* products if they're developed with a specific platform in mind. There are very few products that are identical in both functionality and appearance among multiple platforms that are actually *good*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to run .NET you will need to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) since the Microsoft .NET can't be installed on non-windows machines.

However using Java you can run it on PC, OSX (Mac) and Linux. I would choose Java.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is very augmentative question but it depends on what you already know. If you know java very well that go with it. If you know C# then you have mono to go with for mac. So its your choice.  Since Mono is been actively updated and improved you will have no problem with features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly into .NET. However, in this case I agree Java will be most suitable.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy, try Java. This is platform independent :) Where as .net is a cross-platform language. So have a look at Java :)

Comment: platform independent and cross-platform mean the same thing.